# Integromat merge array - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: arrays, merge, make.com

I have this JSON...

```
    {
        "images": [{
                "id": "ed"
            },
            {
                "id": "frank"
            }
        ],
        "cars": [{
                "id": "11"
            },
            {
                "id": "12"
            }
        ]
    }
```

generating 2 arrays via the "Parse JSON" module...

[image: JSON result]

that I then want to merge into one array using the `merge` function

[image: merge attempt]

but the merge fails with an empty result.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: _"I then want to merge into one array using the merge function"_ - Where is your `marge` function ?

Comment: I just verified on my account and it is working as expectedly, Can you share me the complete scenario if you are still facing the issue?